# Excel equation to add hours to existing cell with date time data

Tags: excel

How to add 8 hours to existing cell

the cell content is "2020-02-14 09:41:52"

Lets say my column is in A1

I've tried

```
=(A1)+8
```

But I'm getting #VALUE!

Comment: Try to use [TimeValue](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/timevalue-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645) function around `A1`

Comment: If you get ```#Value``` error, then there are text, not datetime. And A1 + 8 adds 8 days to the date.To add hours, 8 should be divided by 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that your cell is formatted correctly as date time, then adding integers to date time values in Excel adds to the days. Trying `=A1+8/24` should do the trick.